Installing java on ubuntu running on Windows-subsystem-for-linux
Tyring to run java on Windows-subsystem-for-linux I get:
root@ST-NBXPS33:~# java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with: 
apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.17-75, or 
apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.12+7-1ubuntu2~24.04 
apt install openjdk-21-jre-headless  # version 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04

Then
root@ST-NBXPS33:~# apt install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version (2:1.21-75+exp1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-21-jre but it is not going to be installed
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-21-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
 openlogic-openjdk-17-hotspot : Depends: fonts-dejavu but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@ST-NBXPS33:~#

Then
root@ST-NBXPS33:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-21-jre openjdk-21-jre-headless x11-utils
Suggested packages:
  libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic mesa-utils
Recommended packages:
  luit
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openlogic-openjdk-17-hotspot
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-21-jre openjdk-21-jre-headless x11-utils
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 46.8 MB/47.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 189 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 openjdk-21-jre-headless amd64 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 openjdk-21-jre amd64 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 openjdk-21-jre-headless amd64 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 openjdk-21-jre amd64 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-21/openjdk-21-jre-headless_21.0.4%2b7-1ubuntu2%7e24.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-21/openjdk-21-jre_21.0.4%2b7-1ubuntu2%7e24.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@ST-NBXPS33:~#

So I still have no java. Any ideas?

Your error indicates that it cannot fetch the packages you want to install (code 404). Have you made any changes to /etc/apt/sources.list? If so you might want to restore them to default or place the contents of the file here.

Also if you are working for a company on a company issued machine, your requests might be getting blocked because you do not have the necessary certificates.

404, so it doesn't exist in the archive at that version. Try an apt update to refresh your package lists. Then retry the install.

Post the output of apt update if you see any errors ...

@teapot418 you were right. Please write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Much thanks

Happy to help, but flagging as off-topic, this is more of a Linux&Unix SE type of post.

Looks like your package list is outdated. Try running
apt-get update

If it doesn't resolve the issue then restoring the default repositories might help.
